# Relative path to absolute path in VB.NET

Tags: .net, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I am writing a VB.NET console application where it takes relative paths and spits out all file names, or an error for invalid input. I am having trouble getting PhysicalPath from relative path

Example:

1. I am in folder `C:\Documents and Settings\MehdiAnis.ULTIMATEBANGLA\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SP_Sol\SP_Proj\bin\Debug`
2. My application, `SP.exe`, is also in the same folder.
3. I run: `"SP.exe ..\"`. The output will be a list of all files in the folder `"C:\Documents and Settings\MehdiAnis.ULTIMATEBANGLA\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SP_Sol\SP_Proj\bin"`
4. I run: `"SP.exe ..\\..\"`. The output will be a list of all files in the folder `"C:\Documents and Settings\MehdiAnis.ULTIMATEBANGLA\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SP_Sol\SP_Proj"`
5. I run: `"SP.exe ..\\..\\..\"`. The output will be a list of all files in the folder `"C:\Documents and Settings\MehdiAnis.ULTIMATEBANGLA\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SP_Sol"`

Currently I am handling one relative path, but no more:

```
    If Source.IndexOf("..\") = 0 Then
        Dim Sibling As String = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).ToString()())
        Source = Source.Replace("..\", Sibling)
    End If
```

How can I easily handle multiple `..\`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for [System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  It should handle any type of relative path.

Comment: @Mehdi: Since this looks like it was the solution to your problem, it would be a good idea to mark it as the answer using the checkmark on the left next to the up/down arrows.

Comment: @Zach Johnson: Thanks for showing the CheckMark (TickMark Icon to accept an answer. I didn't know, icon apperas in gray feels like inactive.